# Execution of Selenium scripts in parallel

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit

I have a set of test cases which are automated in Selenium scripts with C# using NUnit project. And I was successfully able to execute them individually. However, I have the requirement where I need to execute this set of test scripts in parallel.

Could you please help out with an approach for running them in parallel, something like the way it is possible for Java using Test NG xml.

Answer (score 0):

The default NUnit runner does not support running tests in parallel. You can create your own test runner to run the tests in parallel (using your current NUnit tests). In my experience [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) worked just fine - it spawns a new thread for each test.

Or you can migrate to [NUnit 3.0](https://github.com/nunit/dev/wiki/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution), since it

> can run tests in parallel within an assembly.

Take a look at the [LevelOfParallelism attribute](https://github.com/nunit/dev/wiki/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution#levelofparallelismattribute).

For

> something like which can be possible in Java using Test NG xml.

The [PNUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=pnunit&r=2.5)'s launcher reads an xml file that specifies the tests to be executed and where they should run, whether on the same machine or on another machine on the network.